# Communication exception using WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf

We've a WPF application(.Net 4.5 framework) deployed to our end users.This communicates with an intranet app server using a WCF service.
This is working fine.Today a new user was added and when he tries to use the app, he always gets this communication exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException: The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error.
```

Existing users dont get this error.Only the new user is getting this issue.

Any pointers please?

Thanks.

Comment: The hint is right there `The server was unable to process the request due to an internal error. `. Do you have any logs you can check, looks like something happened in the application it self, not due to the communication

Comment: You will have to see what error was logged at the server. The client only sees the shielded error, which, in your case,  does not  show much detail.

Comment: Enable [Tracing](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms730342.aspx) on both ends as a start.

Comment: what is the difference between old users and the new user? did you check your object that your are trying to send from WPF to WCF? there might missing or nulls values. You need to debug request code first and then make a break point in your target function in WCF.

Comment: To identify the problem, run the server under debugger, click on Visual studio Main menu "Debug/Exceptions" and tag all CheckBoxes of the first column: you may then see the location of the exception that likely raised the FaultException.

Comment: Check Event Viewer on the server for any errors or enable tracing via server web.config as documented here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733025(v=vs.110).aspx and set switchValue to "Error." This should give better insight into what is causing the problem.